# Incommensurable units as ratios

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, irrational-numbers, ratio

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the concept of an incommensurable unit.

From what I have gathered so far, it is simply a magnitude that cannot be expressed as the ratio of two natural numbers (i.e. $\sqrt{2}$)

However, in the text I am currently reading

> “In describing the concept of a real number, Newton in his “General Arithmetic” wrote: “by number we mean not so much a collection of units, as an abstract ratio of a certain quantity to another quantity taken as the unit.” This number (ratio) may be integral, rational, or if the given magnitude is incommensurable with the unit, irrational.”

Excerpt From: A. D. Aleksandrov. “Mathematics.”

This seems to say that an incommensurable magnitude CAN be expressed as a ratio of "abstract units." Would this imply natural numbers? Maybe my understanding is completely off.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "an incommensurable unit" or "an incommensurable magnitude".

A number can't be "incommensurable". "Incommensurable" means not "commensurable", which in turns means (I'm not a native english speaker, so I won't embarass myself with guesses on the etymology) something like "measurable with the same tool". Technically "two non-zero real numbers a and b are said to be commensurable if a/b is a rational number." ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_%28mathematics%29)). If $b$ is $1$, the condition is that $a$ must be a rational number.

$\sqrt{2}$ is incommensurable with $1$ (or indeed any rational number), but it is commensurable with $\sqrt{8}$ (which is also incommensurable with $1$).

Comment: Is $\sqrt8$/$\sqrt2$ is rational? I want to know that a ratio of two surd is commensurable or incommensurable?or ratio of one surd and one rational number is commensurable?@fleablood

Comment: I mean that which ratio is incommensurable ?ratio of two irrational number or only one irrational and one rational?

Comment: $\sqrt8$/$\sqrt2$ is equal to 2 commensurable right?

Comment: Why do you suddenly start asking new questions in the comments to an answer that's more than a year old? If you have a question, ask it properly.

Comment: Because if I ask the same questions it will became a duplicate

Comment: Since what I want to know is similar to his question but not same